# Android emulator GPU on for NDK apps

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-virtual-device

I have noticed that applications created with the Android SDK are fine using OpenGL ES commands inside an avd with *GPU acceleration on*, on the other hand applications created with the NDK to work with OpenGL ES always fail to even start: is this the expected behaviour for the android emulator ?

To be clear I have no performance issue, the *emulator speed* is fine for other apps, it's "just" the fact that NDK application don't even start if there is OpenGL ES involved.

I'm running my avds under Ubuntu 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Android 4.3 (API Level 18) Intel Atom (x86) AVD with Android NDK R9. OpenGL ES 2.0 acceleration works great for this case. I am using a Macbook Pro with Mac OS X 10.9.1.

Not sure if it matters, but I also have Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) with the Hotfix for Mac OS X 10.9. ([Android emulator freezing OS X v10.9 (Mavericks) with HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243490/android-emulator-freezing-osx-10-9-mavericks-with-haxm))

TL;DR: It works as expected on my development environment, but I think it's safe to assume certain factors might prevent it from working on yours.