# Android emulator freezing OS X v10.9 (Mavericks) with HAXM

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, haxm

I just updated to [OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks), and now whenever I start up any of my emulators, as soon as the emulator starts up, my entire computer freezes with a spinning progress indicator in the center of the screen (not a beachball, the progress indicator is similar to what you see when shutting down, but the screen hasn't faded to grey).

[image: Notice the progress indicator in the bottom center of the screen. The computer is frozen at this point.]

I've tried:

- Turning off GPU acceleration
- Uninstalling and re-installing the latest Intel HAXM
- Re-creating my AVDs
- Updated my Android SDK-Tools

**The only thing that works is to uninstall Intel HAXM / not use hardware acceleration.**

I'm guessing there's a bug with Mavericks and HAXM similar to what motivated the release for 1.0.6 of HAXM for OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion)?

The following crash report is indicating a kernel panic generated by HAXM.

```
Anonymous UUID:       2C84F70F-FE54-51E7-4FBE-6E601ED377AF

Tue Oct  8 21:49:39 2013
Panic(CPU 3): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock: 0xffffff802deca4d8, spinlock owner: 0xffffff80409f4cf0, current_thread: 0xffffff80409f4cf0, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x3
RAX: 0xffffff80409f4cf0, RBX: 0xffffff802ded4c40, RCX: 0xffffff80409f4cf0, RDX: 0x0000000700000000
RSP: 0xffffff8115bb9c30, RBP: 0xffffff8115bb9c70, RSI: 0x0000000792aac9d6, RDI: 0xffffff802deca4d8
R8:  0x0000000000000010, R9:  0x0000000000000269, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000246
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff7faf6b3d92, R14: 0xffffff802deca4d8, R15: 0xffffff802d830040
RFL: 0x0000000000000006, RIP: 0xffffff802d8d0470, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8115bb9aa0 : 0xffffff802d8e21f1
0xffffff8115bb9ad0 : 0xffffff802d8db75f
0xffffff8115bb9b20 : 0xffffff802d8f3930
0xffffff8115bb9c70 : 0xffffff802dbeda5f
0xffffff8115bb9c90 : 0xffffff802d82f741
0xffffff8115bb9dc0 : 0xffffff802d830018
0xffffff8115bb9e30 : 0xffffff7faf6a7f86
0xffffff8115bb9ed0 : 0xffffff802d8e351e
0xffffff8115bb9f10 : 0xffffff802d8e2e3e
0xffffff8115bb9f50 : 0xffffff802d8e21c6
0xffffff8115bb9f80 : 0xffffff802d8db75f
0xffffff8115bb9fd0 : 0xffffff802d8f37c9
0xffffff815a62bd00 : 0xffffff802d9fd8bd
0xffffff815a62bd80 : 0xffffff802d9f3787
0xffffff815a62bdc0 : 0xffffff802dbf0eeb
0xffffff815a62beb0 : 0xffffff802dbf0b88
0xffffff815a62bf50 : 0xffffff802dc3de23
0xffffff815a62bfb0 : 0xffffff802d8f3e06
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.intel.kext.intelhaxm(1.0.6)[49CE9C16-9447-31FE-A856-4BDD043A302D]@0xffffff7faf6a6000->0xffffff7faf6c2fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: syslogd

Mac OS version:
13A598

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x000000002d600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802d800000
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5867020237
last loaded kext at 5616463499: com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.0.6 (addr 0xffffff7faf6a6000, size 118784)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.0.6
com.razerzone.razerapo    1.00.84
com.cyberic.SmoothMouse    7
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver    1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM    100.14.11
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver    2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA    2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU    4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP    1.0.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver    2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC    1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight    170.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl    1.1.12
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver    240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard    240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver    3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache    35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter    404
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331    700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI    650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI    650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager    161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient    216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    153
com.apple.security.quarantine    3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement    216.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    3.6.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib    2.5.2fc2
com.apple.vecLib.kext    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily    2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily    5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController    1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC    3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch    240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily    2.8.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController    1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient    650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family    600.34
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox    278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages    371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore    28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread    1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff802dbeda5f): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff802deca4d8, lock owner thread=0xffffff80409f4cf0, current_thread: 0xffffff8040364450, lock owner active on CPU 0x3, current owner: 0xffffff80409f4cf0"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:365
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff815a5db810 : 0xffffff802d822f69
0xffffff815a5db890 : 0xffffff802dbeda5f
0xffffff815a5db8b0 : 0xffffff802d82f741
0xffffff815a5db9e0 : 0xffffff802d830018
0xffffff815a5dba50 : 0xffffff7faf6a7f86
0xffffff815a5dbaf0 : 0xffffff802d8e351e
0xffffff815a5dbb30 : 0xffffff802d8e3c78
0xffffff815a5dbb70 : 0xffffff7faf6b01e0
0xffffff815a5dbba0 : 0xffffff7faf6aa2e0
0xffffff815a5dbbe0 : 0xffffff7faf6a6e3c
0xffffff815a5dbc00 : 0xffffff802dc58316
0xffffff815a5dbc60 : 0xffffff802dc56051
0xffffff815a5dbcb0 : 0xffffff802dc5497e
0xffffff815a5dbd10 : 0xffffff802dc5465c
0xffffff815a5dbd80 : 0xffffff802dc67074
0xffffff815a5dbe10 : 0xffffff802d85c590
0xffffff815a5dbe50 : 0xffffff802d826bb1
0xffffff815a5dbe80 : 0xffffff802d8139b5
0xffffff815a5dbef0 : 0xffffff802d81e003
0xffffff815a5dbf70 : 0xffffff802d8c921d
0xffffff815a5dbfb0 : 0xffffff802d8f3e26
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.intel.kext.intelhaxm(1.0.6)[49CE9C16-9447-31FE-A856-4BDD043A302D]@0xffffff7faf6a6000->0xffffff7faf6c2fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kextd

System Profile:
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034302E413031472020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034302E413031472020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: OCZ-VERTEX3, 120.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034302E413031472020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034302E413031472020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: OCZ-VERTEX3, 120.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Comment: Added the crash report. Kernel panic.

Comment: Have you reported this to Intel?

Comment: I couldn't figure out where to report it to... Was also not sure if this is actually a Mavericks issue since it was caused by Mavericks...

Comment: It is a Mavericks issue as it was caused by Mavericks. The info may hep them if they haven't started working on it yet.

Comment: You can report it at the link below. I notice that an Intel representative is answering the thread and passing issues on to the tech team. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-macosx give the as much information as possible.

Comment: Anyone try the new GM just stealthily released today?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Intel released a hotfix for the Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM). If you have installed HAXM on Microsoft Windows* 8.1 or OS X 10.9 you should install the Hotfix.

Download of the hotfix from the HAXM download page: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

Thanks,
Alex (Intel)

-edit-

It looks like the hotfix link has been moved (temporarily? ...). Use this link to get to the OSX Hotfix:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macos-hotfix

Comment: Using intellij, this whole process was the only thing that worked for my emulator on Mavericks. "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode" such a beautiful thing to see--thing runs like 50x faster

Comment: This did not work for me. The HAXM hotfix installs correctly so +1 for that (e.g. kextstat | grep intel) on my OS X 10.9.1 machine giving: "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
[2014-01-28 13:13:16 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-01-28 13:13:16 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...". However, the emulator for an AVD with x86 CPU (and no host GPU acceleration) hangs here showing the android logo.

Comment: Note: I also enabled host GPU acceleration but no change. This page is helpful: http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture

Comment: Note: I have installed the x86 Atom System Image (mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059919/intel-x86-emulator-starts-but-android-doesnt-boot/21060004#21060004).

Comment: This is also helpful: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Comment: Pls Help: The emulator still doesn't launch even w/ the hotfix (display is stuck at the "android" spinner). I have 1024M unused so HAXM should be able to reserve 512Mb but dmesg shows: 
haxm_error: Memory allocation, va:11b0b5000, size:20000000
haxm_error: !VM_STATE_FLAGS_MEM_ALLOC: spare_ram 0x5800000
haxm_error: hax_vm_alloc_ram: size 0x20000
haxm_error: spare alloc: mem_limit 0x20000000, size 0x20000, spare_ram 0x5800000
haxm_error: VM_STATE_FLAGS_MEM_ALLOC: spare_ram 0x57e0000
haxm_error: hax_vm_alloc_ram: size 0x20000

Comment: The download link has moved again. Now it's https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager. But the best general solution seems to be to go to https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/ and look around for a link to download HAXM.

Comment: This answer also helpful for Tizen emulator, but it is not founded by "Tizen emulator launch problem" google request, it would be grate if somebody adds Tizen tag for that question

Answer (score 60):

Good news! The great guys at Intel are currently testing a fix and are testing it now (Alexander from Intel's response pasted below)

> Hi,
>
> We identified the root cause of this issue. The Intel HaXM team is
>   testing an update to support newly released OSes (Microsoft Windows*
>   8.1 and OS X Mavericks*). Look for word on our upcoming update.
>
> Thanks, Alex

This is a known issue though Mavericks GM has only been released to developers recently. I have notified Intel here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/477793

UPDATE:

THIS IS A RESPONSE FROM INTEL I HAVE PASTED BELOW FROM THEIR FORUM

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for your replies. We are investigating into this issue at the
>   moment. Please note that OS X 10.9 is not an supported OS version for
>   the actual version of HAXM. I will update this thread as soon as I
>   have new information or a fix/workaround is available.
>
> Thanks, Alex
>
> Click here to view this Forum topic and respond: 
>   http://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1761988#comment-1761988

And a further update:

> We identified the root cause of this issue. The Intel HaXM team is testing an update to support newly released OSes (Microsoft Windows* 8.1 and OS X Mavericks*). Look for word on our upcoming update.

Another update:

> I assume we release a fix somewhere between a few days and two weeks. We know that a lot of people are waiting for the fix, so we try to release it as fast as possible.
>
> Thanks for your patience!

INTEL HAVE PROVIDED A HOTFIX

> Great news: The hotfix is available for download! Please go to http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/. There is a hotfix for Microsoft Windows* 8.1 and one for OS X 10.9. 
>   Let us know if the hotfix is working for you.
>
> Thanks all for helping us resolving this issue!

Comment: Awesome thanks, I did leave a comment yesterday but it didn't show up, I thought it must be moderation.

Comment: A nice gentleman from Intel answered and asked for the kernel log. I sent it to him on the same thread. I'll continue commenting here as things change.

Comment: In the mean time I have been using Genymotion though I could do with their VMs having root access so I can access the databases. On the plus side the VMs have full Google Play Services including the Play Store.

Comment: They aren't launching for me on 10.9 either.  Seems like a VirtualBox issue.

Comment: GenyMotion is working fine on my Mac, so I'm not sure how much you could call it a VirtualBox issue.

Comment: Pork 'n' Bunny, it may well be a VIrtualBox issue/Mavericks compatibility issues as people with some models get it to work fine while others need to install the latest VirtualBox update before Genymotion will work again.

Comment: Aah ok so an update may have addressed the similar issue for virtualbox.

Comment: So Pork 'n' Bunny can you accept this answer there is a fix released now cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Fix worked for me. Back to fast emulator for me.

Comment: I'm showing it as running ("HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode") but Android Studio consistently loses connection to the emulator and shows "No Connected Devices" inside the DDMS "Devices" tab. It might show "Emulator null" while it's loading, but it just doesn't connect. This is frustrating beyond belief...can't AVD Manager > Start, can't change Run Configs to choose or open specific emulator...does anyone else have these problems?? You should be able to open your project and "Run" to open the emulator, but it just doesn't work...almost ever...

Answer (score 9):

It seems like problems will persist even if you install and run getting "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode."  If you have Xcode open when running Android Studio, it appears that Xcode is reserving a partition for its simulator even if the sim isn't open.

You might see a "No Connected Devices" in the "6. Android" tab but see it running in the DDMS.  You might also see the "Emulator null 5556 [OFFLINE]" show up then loose connection and revert back to "Not Connected Devices."

I've been using the HAXM emulator successfully for a while on my Mac Mini 4GB RAM machine, but as soon as I tried running the Nexus 10 emulator, I starting to see a ton of problems launching the app.

The long and short of it is that you need to close/disable Xcode, VirtualBox, Hyper-V, or any other VM that uses virtualization technology to run the HAXM emulator and the default emulator efficiently.

After closing Xcode, I was able to open the emulator with no problems right off the bat, most likely because of the the CPU restrictions of my system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still getting kernel panics with the supposed fix above but now I think I know why. I have VMWare Fusion installed and it's always running in the background so it's probably causing all the trouble.

Comment: This! This was super helpful, I had both xcode and vbox running. Shutting them down did the trick.  Sucks I can't use my vbox server env with a decent android emulator though =/

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this answer. I have Macbook Air the newest one and the solution was that I needed to close VirtualBox. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For those of us using older Macs, in particular Core Duo 2 machines, I think there's still a problem.  I have an early 2009 iMac with 8GB RAM running Yosemite (10.10.1) and I installed the 1.1.1 version of HAXM (tried both the version that Android SDK Manager downloaded and the one referenced above on Intel's site).

I can run the older ARM images, but like many others who are having issues running the x86 images, e.g. Nexus 5, Nexus 6, it still hangs for me.

In https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/536330, there are a couple of people who are having issues with Core Duo 2 Mavericks machines.  It states in the HAXM 1.1.1 `Release Notes.txt` file:

> HAXM driver does not support emulating a 64 bit system image on Intel systems based on Core microarchitecture (Core, Core2 Duo etc.).

But, it seems like even trying to emulate a 32 bit system is problematic.

NB: ARM images work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The hotfix (almost) solved it for me.  After installing the hotfix my emulator was still not using HAXM.  I had to uninstall the old version using the SDK manager.  Once I did that I was able to get HAXM running.  You can tell it is running by looking for the message in the startup window when you start a new emulator.

Comment: Have you ran into the problems I mentioned in Panalover's answer?  Does this have something to do with the fact I have a MacMini with 4GB of RAM?  I've tried edi the AVD to use 1024MB and had it working efficiently using 600MB, but I just can't get any Intel Atom enabled emulators to run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Hotfix worked on my Macbook Retina with 10.9.  I installed the HAX from Android SDK manager version 3 and it froze on my AVD (x86 CPU using HOST GPU).  I downloaded and installed the hotfix without uninstalling HAX version 3 (do a kextstat | grep intel to confirm the version).

The AVD booted in less than 10 seconds....