# Android emulator: 'HAX is working' but emulator unbearably slow on fast PC

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, haxm

I have Intel HAX installed, with the [OS X 10.9 hotfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243490/android-emulator-freezing-osx-10-9-mavericks-with-haxm), and am launching the emulator with:

```
~/Applications/AndroidDevTools/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Android43Fast
```

When the emulator runs I recieve:

> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

The emulator runs around 5-6 frames a second, with a visible redraw rate and serious latency. The machine is an MBA 2013, with 512GB SSD and 8GB RAM.

- Is HAX really running? I receive the message, but I don't trust it. Performance doesn't resemble Intel's HAX videos at all, and does not seem faster than the regular emulator.
- How can I make the emulator run with acceptable latency, with or without HAX?

Comment: I have hot fix installed, but get a message "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode". Did you need to do any extra steps besides hot fix?

Comment: Sorry @GnrlBzik I gave up on having the Android emulator working, and used an physical device instead.

Comment: I got it working in my instance, don't know if it might be any help, we do have different issues, but take a look at my so question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode/21057685?noredirect=1#21057685 may be it will help.

Comment: I have the same problem. My computer has an Intel Core 2 Q6600 CPU. The emulator reports that HAX is working, but it runs very slowly and unstably.