# Android Emulator Issue

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Whenever I am running my Android application in Android Studio , I am not getting output on my AVD , instead I am getting error in consle

**emulator: device fd:680
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered**

One more issue is whenever I am running application in my phone after the execution of 2nd or 3rd application I am getting error that

**unfortunately app has stopped**

Comment: Check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have downloaded HAXM using AVD Manager or manually from any website.

While installing intelhaxm_android.exe(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) put the RAM space allocation to default which may be 2GB.

I was facing the same problem but it worked after re-installing with 2GB RAM space instead of 1GB which I initially selected. For complete guidance you can refer to: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows