# Android Studio Emulator memory error

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, limit, ram

System notes:
1. Using Android Studio 1.1.0
2. Using Windows 8.1, 32 bit
3. Using JDK 7
4. 512mb was given to the emulator and Intel HAXM is installed and in use.

Hello!
My Android Studio emulator memory is being stupid. When I try to run an AVD, it does the normal stuff, then gives me this error message:

```
The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
```

I fully understand that it is exceeding my PC RAM, however I can't fix this error as I can't find where to lower the memory allowance. Also, 512mb is the recommended amount, so will lowering the allowance have a bad effect?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocated has to be lower or equal to the memory usage you have set during the installation of HAXM. Relaunch the installation and modify it.

*This answer belongs to **ph0b** from: [How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)*

Comment: I need to relaunch the HAXM installation in the SDK Manager? Do I then set it to 512mb? I was never given that option to start with so I have no idea how much memory it uses. I set 512mb in the initial Android Studio installation.

Comment: I still need some help. Regarding my previous comment, any help please?

Comment: Look at the answers from here first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode , I think you should to relaunch the instalation from the SDK Manager, if there is something like an edit option it would be great.