# Intel HAXM / Android Studio in OS X 10.11 / El Capitan

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, haxm

I recently tried to set up a new instance of Android Studio on OS X 10.11 (did not have it set up before upgrading) and have been getting the following issue:

[image: HAXM Error]

Following that, I tried to resolve the issue by installing HAXM via ADT or even intel's site at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx

However, neither the regular HAXM installer or the hot fix version are compatible with OS X 10.11, as the installer insists it's not compatible with this version of OS X.

The question now is whether or not anyone else has succeeded in installing HAXM on 10.11 or if it's an issue that will not be resolved until either Android Studio or a the HAXM installer is updated?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Proposed solution does not work as I cannot run the HAXM installer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)

Comment: The Android SDK supports up to Mac OS X v10.9 (Mavericks). See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for more info. So, HAXM is not the culprit in this case.

Comment: The [Intel HAXM version from July 17](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx) installs and works on El Capitan Beta 5 for me.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, wasn't working on El Capitan Beta 1.

Comment: Apparently 5.5.0 was just pushed out, anybody know if it works with El Capitan?  Even better yet does it work with the most recent virtual box?

Comment: @arcade16 how did you solve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read this post: [How to fix: “HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask && brew update
brew cask install intel-haxm
```

**Note**: I have experience only with Maverick and Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this did not work. I received the following error: 
"Warning: caskroom/cask/brew-cask-0.54.1 already installed
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: "

Comment: Was able to run the first command to instal brew cask and run brew update, but the second command fails with the error: "==> installer: Error - A newer version of Intel HAXM is already installed on this computer. Installation will exit."

Comment: Thanks! I removed haxm using the uninstall command on intel's site, but now get the following error when trying to install it with brew: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)

Comment: I think intel-haxm not support your version (El Capitan). Maybe is good idea to report a new issue: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues

Comment: Automatic installation still doesn't work, but I successfully manually installed it on my preview El Capitan (OS X 10.11) today.