# Android Virtual Device Not Loading

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I started AVD To get Start at 8:00pm. And its been 2 hours since the AVD to load. It is the first time. I have 4 gb of RAM, and have allocated 2gb to Intel HAXM.
I got this  on the output screen too.

```
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
```

Any Help would be nice

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM is set for use inside your AVD configuration?

Most importantly this number has to be lower or equal to the memory usage you have set during the installation of HAXM.

Have you looked at :[How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)

Not sure if this will help since you allocated 2gb to Intel HAXM and the AVD is most likely not using more than that.