# AVD not start black screen with ANDROID label

Tags: android

I install the android studio and when I try to start `AVD(NEXUS 5)` this is
not working. AVD screen show black screen with android label. I wait about 30 mint
but AVD not start.
console show the error

```
hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode
```

I reduce the `RAM` set to 1GB not working.
I set `RAM` to 512MB not working.
I also uncheck the `use gpu host` but all in vain.
I check the `HAXLog` file but there is nothing.
My machine is `core i3` windows 7.
It support the `virtualization technology` and this is also enable from the `boot` menu.
How I can overcome from this problem.
THANKS...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode

Comment: Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide) instead

Comment: its alternative not solution

Answer (score 0):

After adding an AVD, it takes a long time to run. On my less than year old Core2Duo 2.8 GHz running Win7x64 and 4Gb of RAM, initializing a 2.2 version took at least 5 to 10 minutes (if not longer). Once it starts initializing you can watch the logcat in the DDMS panel of eclipse and watch it unpack and install all of the apps in the emulator.