# HAXM Android virtual device is not running

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I am using 'android studio' for first time . Trying to run emulator but its take hours , doesn't show android mobile. Only its showing 'Android' in large text.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

I read many blog and article , including 
[How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)

But still don't have solutions.

Any help please.

Thanks

Comment: my problem was regarding HAX is not working or for AVD out of memory. And i already mention that, i read and try different solutions , which is not works. also included screenshot. 
That's the reason , i am here. If you can help me, which will be grate .

Comment: As mentioned by Shlublu, you need to make sure that AVD does not have higher memory limit than the HAXM. Either you can reduce AVD memory or you can increase HAXM memory by running HAXM installer again. Solution is already mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29288735/2073920

Comment: @hassan How much assigned memory do you end up with?

Comment: i tried  with 896mb and 1 GB ram, in both way don't work it.

Comment: @hassan Maybe you should give a try with a smaller device, like a generic one.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on windows7

Answer (score 0):

The HAXM memory limit has to cover more than the memory assigned to you virtual device.

According to the log above, the amount of memory assigned to the device ("AVD RAM size", set to 1536MB) exceeds the memory limit of HAXM ("Max RAM size", currently set to 512MB). You have to adjust that: by running the HAXM installer, you can set the "Max RAM size" limit to 2048MB (or more should your physical machine be able to handle that) instead of the 512MB currently handled.

-> HAXM installer documentation: [for Windows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) - [for MacOS X](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

If your physical machine cannot afford assigning 2048MB or more to HAXM, assign as much as you reasonably can to HAXM (mine is 1024MB), and assign less memory to your virtual device. Be careful though, on my side I couldn't have a API 23 emulator running well with less than 768MB assigned (and 64MB for the heap).

-> To change the memory settings of your virtual device, you have to go to the "Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager", and then to edit your device. I highlighted this in the picture below.

[image]

I'm using Eclipse, but the process should be similar under Android Studio.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your sugession. please can you tell me , how can assigned memory size ? Is that tools -> AVD Manager,

Comment: @hassan You have to use the virtual device manager. I included a screenshot to my answer. But you also have to run the HAXM installer to increase its own memory limit.

Comment: Yes, i set same ram size and other settings , but still not works :(

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to work with Android Studio built in AVD then consider installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM). To find it, open Tools>Android>SDK Manager, then scroll down on the screen to Extras. You will see it as a last option. This would speed up things for better. 
[image]
Much better solution will be to use genymotion. You can install it for free and it's way faster. 
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide