# How to fix: HAXM silent installation only support mac OS X from 10.8 to 10.10

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm, osx-elcapitan

After updated my Mac to OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 I couldn't create new virtual devices in Android Studio

From now, when I create a New Virtual Device and run my application I have the following message:

```
> emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in
> your HAXM configuration. HAXM is not working and emulator runs in
> emulation mode emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB emulator: HAXM
> max RAM size = 512 MB emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM
> size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode. emulator:
> emulator window was out of view and was recentered emulator:
> UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288735/2091181) answer to resolve the problem but when I try to installing it again I have the following message:

> HAXM silent installation only support mac OS X from 10.8 to 10.10 !

So, What is the proper way to install the HAXM kernel extension on 10.11 El Capitan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem and it had resolved by manually install HAXM latest version for Mac OS 10.11.

1. Download haxm-macosx_r05.zip (1.1.5) from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/
2. Run "HAXM installation" file from terminal.

I hope it helpful.

Comment: I did this and it installed. But when I tried running the emulator it gave these lines..


`emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg`

`emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context`

Comment: I haven't got this problem. Nothing to say about it :(

Comment: I got an update notification on my Android Studio just 10 mins ago asking my to update haxm, that there is a new update to v5.5. I updated it, and all of a sudden this error is gone. My Android x86-image based emulator is fast again. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem on macOS 10.13: "HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12".
I simply dowloaded the zip linked in this answer and installed HAXM from the dmg file.

Comment: AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges failed with return: -60031

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed, you can do it like this:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/intel-haxm
```

Here's the formulae, it currently points to version 7.2.0:
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/14a0a23ae84df4e3d8a4be60b19e8ddb269415ec/Casks/intel-haxm.rb