# how to decrease size of avd ram of emulator?

Tags: android, haxm

I am trying to decrease my avd ram size from 1024mb to 512 mb. However when am running my application the ram is again 1024mb. Can someone help me?

Thats why am getting:
Haxm not working and emulator runs in emulation mode.

Comment: I believe Hamx doesn't work for 512mb of RAM. See what RAM size you have allocated to Hamx while installation and use any RAM size greater than that. This would solve your Hamx issue.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode

Comment: My ram size for haxm is 512 mb. I had set my ram size to about 1024mb (default). Yet am getting same problem: max avd size:1024mb and max hamx size is 512. Means i have to decrease avd ram size because it says the memory located by this avd EXCEEDS the max specified in your haxm configuration. How to decrease ram size then?

Comment: I believe it doesn't work for 512mb. Try increasing Hamx RAM size to 768mb minimum.

Comment: I have increased haxm size to 768 mb.yet same problem.