# Android Emulator I/O warning

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting an I/O warning as follows, How to solve it ? Thanks

> C:\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_19
>   emulator: device fd:772
>   HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
>   creating window 43 59 329 583
>   emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>   **I/O warning : failed to load external entity "file:/C:/Users/pavilion%2015/.AndroidStudioPreview2.0/config/options/usage.statistics.xml"**
>   emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)