# Android Emulator stopped working

Tags: android, android-emulator

For some reason my emulator isn't working (even though it previously worked just fine). The emulator launches but my app doesn't. The errors are:

```
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB

emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB

emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.

emulator: device fd:1140

HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

emulator: HAXM does not have enough memory remaining to load this AVD.

emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB

emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB (for all running AVDs)

emulator: Try creating an AVD that requires less RAM or re-running the HAXM installer to set a higher memory limit. The HAXM installer may be found at ....

emulator: Failed to get Hax capability:6
```

**It was working fine** (app and everything launched), but these errors appeared about today. How can I fix it?

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode

Comment: Use ubuntu )) no haxm, no problems. KVM works good for me

Answer (score -1):

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EolJu.png) Android Emulator Firstly run,but after some seconds its automatically stopped.

To Fix this problem you need to graphics driver installation of your computer.