# Emulator of android studio not working even BIOS VT-X setting is enabled

Tags: android, android-emulator

"E:\Software\Android Studio\Android Studio\android-sdks\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

when run my app on emulator above error occurs. I've installed Intel HAXM in android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can fix this by set your RAM to the prefered Size.

First in android studio

Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Your Device > Pencil Icon> Show Advanced Settings > Memory and Storage > RAM > Set RAM to your preferred size.

And then in the control panel

Programs and Features > Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager > Change > Set manually > Set RAM to your preferred size.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode?rq=1)
Hope that solves the problem. Have a nice day.