# Intel x86 emulator starts but android doesn't boot

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I want to run my app on a emulator api level 10 using Intel HAX technology. I've downloaded the HAXM package from sdk manager and installed it. I've also enabled the "Virtualization technology" in BIOS setting (Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android) thread) but when start the emulator screen keeps black and android doesn't boot/start. Here's the Avd message on starting emulator:

[image]

Please help me, I've no idea what's wrong!

(My pc config: Windows 7 - 64bit, 4gig RAM, intel M 520 2.4 GHz, working on eclipse)

### Edit:

Here is the console messages after running emulator:

```
[2014-01-11 12:14:24 - BabbageTuring] ------------------------------
[2014-01-11 12:14:24 - BabbageTuring] Android Launch!
[2014-01-11 12:14:24 - BabbageTuring] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-11 12:14:24 - BabbageTuring] Performing com.illinois.babbageturing.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-11 12:14:28 - BabbageTuring] Launch canceled!
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] Updated AVD '480x800' based on Android 2.3.3, Intel Atom (x86) processor,
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=no
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=240
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=1318766497
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=3.7in WVGA (Nexus One)
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.gpu.enabled=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=yes
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=no
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=32
[2014-01-11 12:14:47 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
```

Answer (score 4):

I am on Windows 7 too and can't get API 10 to work with the Intel x86 image, unless I set the RAM to 768 (max for Windows and far more than devices had then) and turn off "Use Host GPU".

Comment: That worked! But android.process.acore frequently stops and there's not much difference in performance (comparing to armeabi)

Comment: I think RAM isn't the problem. Disabling "Use Host GPU" solved it for me, and the performance isn't terribly bad. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have the right x86 image installed corresponding to the API level. You can find [x86 image distribution here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/25553)

I have seen that decreasing the RAM size works, when the system is running low on RAM. 512MB would be ideal in most scenarios. Please enable "Use Host GPU" and make sure you are selecting x86 from the drop down box on AVD.

Refer to [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture) for more information

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use API Level 10?  The minimal requirements for HAXM is API level 17.  Here are some links that might be helpful to look at:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm

Answer (score 1):

To use the graphics acceleration feature make sure you have

Android SDK Tools - Revision 17 +
Android SDK Platform API 15 - Revision 3+

Download the intel x86 images from http://www.intel.com/software/android
Click on tools and navigate to bottom of the page for the details

I hope you have already installed intel HAXM and its running else please refer https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Moreover, it worked for me only when I checked Use Host GPU option.

I know I am late but I hope it will help the new users like me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded Intel x86 Atom System Image? That's the image required for running on HAX
[image]

Comment: Yes. I've downloaded that.

Comment: Are you getting any log messages in console? Please post them