# Why does Aptana not start on 13.10?

Tags: javascript, php, eclipse, aptana, ubuntu-13.10

The latest Aptana Studio just shows its loading screen, and disappears, on Ubuntu 13.10.

There is not even an error when I run the standalone Aptana from the command line.

Is there a workaround for this? And is Aptana actually just Eclipse, PDT, Javascript modules from Eclipse, packaged together? (Eclipse has very limited JS support, and copy support, which is making me consider others like Aptana.)

How can I debug this to get a proper bug report?

Comment: Aptana support redirects to here though... clarified the question

Comment: "Why does x/y/z IDE completely not work with x/y/z OS" is a relevant and good question for programmers - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243490, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816679/android-unknown-command-crunch