# blank screen with android emulator on mac

Tags: android

I installed android-sdk via brew on my mac: `brew install android-sdk` and then I install api 19 and setup a device.

But when I boot the emulator, it just hangs on a black screen.

Comment: Whats the Configuration of your Mac PC, Emulator Doesn't work smoothly on lower Configurations. Have a Look for more infor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243490/android-emulator-freezing-osx-10-9-mavericks-with-haxm

Comment: I found the android studio bundle for mac to be very good at properly configuring the emulator with x86 images for speed. Did you at least use an x86 image?

Comment: mac is about 6 months old top of the line. mbp.